# Hmaster not starting Hadoop 3.3.5 / hbase 2.4.17

Tags: hbase

Installed hadoop 3.3.5. On Single node server.

File hbase-site.xml contains

```
<configuration>
  <property>
          <name>hbase.master.namespace.init.timeout</name>
    <value>2400000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.executor.openregion.threads</name>
    <value>20</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:54310/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
 </property>
 <property>
      <name>hbase.master.ipc.address</name>
      <value>localhost</value>    </property>
       <property>
      <name>hbase.master.hostname</name>
      <value>localhost</value>    </property>
   <property>
      <name>hbase.regionserver.hostname</name>
      <value>localhost</value>    </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.ipc.address</name>
    <value>localhost</value>   </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/apache-zookeeper/</value>
  </property>
  <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.home.dir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/hadoop</value>
   </property>
   <property>
            <name>hbase.master</name>
            <value>localhost:60000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
      <value>2181</value>
      <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
      The port at which the clients will connect.
      </description>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>hbase.master.hostname</name>
    <value>master.local</value>
    <!-- master.local is the DNS name in my network pointing to hbase master -->
  </property>
</configuration>
```

hbase-env.sh contains
`export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false

```
jps output:
`hduser@mail:/usr/local/hbase/conf> jps
22418 DataNode
22770 ResourceManager
22930 NodeManager
1925 Jps
327 QuorumPeerMain
856 HRegionServer
22237 NameNode
```

Getting Failure:

```
2023-08-01 00:22:36,806 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib
2023-08-01 00:22:36,806 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2023-08-01 00:22:36,806 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2023-08-01 00:22:36,806 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2023-08-01 00:22:36,806 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
2023-08-01 00:22:36,806 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=5.3.18-22-default
2023-08-01 00:22:36,806 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=hduser
2023-08-01 00:22:36,806 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/hduser
2023-08-01 00:22:36,806 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/usr/local/hbase/bin
2023-08-01 00:22:36,807 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.PendingWatcher@3a6f2de3
2023-08-01 00:22:36,814 INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2023-08-01 00:22:36,818 INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
2023-08-01 00:22:39,813 INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x1006c4c36560000, negotiated timeout = 40000
2023-08-01 00:22:39,855 INFO  [main] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Node /hbase already exists and this is not a retry
2023-08-01 00:22:39,875 INFO  [RpcServer.responder] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.responder: starting
2023-08-01 00:22:39,875 INFO  [RpcServer.listener,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.listener,port=60000: starting
2023-08-01 00:22:39,907 INFO  [master:roadrunner-com:60000] mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2023-08-01 00:22:39,926 INFO  [master:roadrunner-com:60000] http.HttpServer: Added global filter 'safety' (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter)
2023-08-01 00:22:39,927 INFO  [master:roadrunner-com:60000] http.HttpServer: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context master
2023-08-01 00:22:39,927 INFO  [master:roadrunner-com:60000] http.HttpServer: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context static
2023-08-01 00:22:39,931 INFO  [master:roadrunner-com:60000] http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 60010
2023-08-01 00:22:39,931 INFO  [master:roadrunner-com:60000] mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2023-08-01 00:22:40,084 INFO  [master:roadrunner-com:60000] mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:60010
2023-08-01 00:22:40,135 DEBUG [main-EventThread] master.ActiveMasterManager: A master is now available
2023-08-01 00:22:40,137 INFO  [master:roadrunner-com:60000] master.ActiveMasterManager: Registered Active Master=roadrunner-com.msg.pkvw.co.charter.net,60000,1690874556592
2023-08-01 00:22:40,140 INFO  [master:roadrunner-com:60000] Configuration.deprecation: fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2023-08-01 00:22:40,159 FATAL [master:roadrunner-com:60000] master.HMaster: Unhandled exception. Starting shutdown.
java.net.ConnectException: Call From mail/47.43.26.44 to localhost:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:783)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:730)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1351)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.setSafeMode(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.setSafeMode(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:561)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.setSafeMode(DFSClient.java:2146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.setSafeMode(DistributedFileSystem.java:983)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.setSafeMode(DistributedFileSystem.java:967)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.isInSafeMode(FSUtils.java:474)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.waitOnSafeMode(FSUtils.java:921)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.checkRootDir(MasterFileSystem.java:443)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.createInitialFileSystemLayout(MasterFileSystem.java:154)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.<init>(MasterFileSystem.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishInitialization(HMaster.java:898)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.run(HMaster.java:698)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:715)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:529)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:493)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:547)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:642)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2600(Client.java:314)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1399)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1318)
        ... 22 more
2023-08-01 00:22:40,160 INFO  [master:roadrunner-com:60000] master.HMaster: Aborting
2023-08-01 00:22:40,160 DEBUG [master:roadrunner-com:60000] master.HMaster: Stopping service threads
2023-08-01 00:22:40,161 INFO  [master:roadrunner-com:60000] ipc.RpcServer: Stopping server on 60000
2023-08-01 00:22:40,161 INFO  [RpcServer.listener,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.listener,port=60000: stopping
2023-08-01 00:22:40,161 INFO  [RpcServer.responder] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.responder: stopped
2023-08-01 00:22:40,161 INFO  [RpcServer.responder] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.responder: stopping
2023-08-01 00:22:40,161 INFO  [master:roadrunner-com:60000] master.HMaster: Stopping infoServer
2023-08-01 00:22:40,171 INFO  [master:roadrunner-com:60000] mortbay.log: Stopped SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:60010
2023-08-01 00:22:40,303 INFO  [main-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
2023-08-01 00:22:40,303 INFO  [master:roadrunner-com:60000] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x1006c4c36560000 closed
2023-08-01 00:22:40,303 INFO  [master:roadrunner-com:60000] master.HMaster: HMaster main thread exiting
2023-08-01 00:22:40,303 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: HMaster Aborted
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:207)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:135)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:127)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:3164)
```

Expect HMaster to start I tried different versions of Hbase 2.3/1.1.2 but it is failing with same error as above. I configured /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname file as well but it is not working.
Earlier Hbase was working with hadoop 2.x and hbase 0.94